# canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 causes 'Bad Access' in iOS4

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

Here is my code:

```
if( [self.captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080] == YES )
    {
    [self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080];
    self.currentPreset = GMCVideoCaptureRecordingPresetFullHD;
    }
```

On iOS4 execution stops on the first line with 'Bad access' error.
On iOS5 it works fine.

How to correctly check for compatibility here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080` is an `NSString *const`. You can just check that its address is not `NULL`. So like so:

```
if( &AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 != NULL && [self.captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080] == YES )
{
    [self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080];
    self.currentPreset = GMCVideoCaptureRecordingPresetFullHD;
}
```

That should do what you want. Note that you won't be setting the preset on < iOS 5 though so you will presumably want an `else` in there to handle the case of it being < iOS 5 or the 1920x1080 preset can't be set.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to check AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 against nil, which was wrong practice.